# Detecting class type and redirect to correct method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have three classes:

```
public AccountTable { void insert(Account account){}}
public CustmerTable { void insert(Customer customer){}}
public TransactionTable { void insert(Transaction Transaction){}}
```

and an endpoint which receives a message class for insertion as:

```
public message {
    Entity entity; //after deserialization, becomes Account, Customer or Transaction
    String entityName; //contains class of the entity
}
```

How can I redirect to the correct insertion method? The only solution I'm seeing is check using `istanceOf` and use `switch/if`, but I don't think that's much scalable if more classes get added, and I can't change Customer, Account or Transaction, as they are legacy code and very sensitive to changes.

Comment: So, all of  `Account`, `Customer` and `Transaction` extend `Entity` ?

Comment: Nope, `Entity` contains a Json, which comes from front-end and need deserialization to one of those classes, which I already managed to do.

Comment: you can make the three classes as implementations for a interface and then use the interface based on the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
public interface Saveable <T> {
    void save(T entity);
}

public class AccountSaver implements Saveable<Account> {
    void save(Account account){
        // ... save account
    }
}

public class CustomerSaver implements Saveable<Customer> {
    void save(Customer customer){
        // ... save customer
    }
}

public class TransactionSaver implements Saveable<Transaction> {
    void save(Transaction transaction){
        // ... save transaction
    }
}
```

Comment: Then I just call `Saveable.save` on the entity?

Comment: You can have a wrapper which has a `Saveable` as field, which will be instantiated to one of the concrete savers according to some parameter (the type of the object you deserialized).Sort of strategy pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if Class1/2/3 are service you manage, and you already managed json to right class,

then i'll create a service like

```
public class MyService {
@Autowired
List<ClasseX> services;

public void save(Object obj){
    for (ClasseX service : services) {
        if(service.accept(obj)){
            service.save(obj);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and add a method on ClassX, where each instance will do the `instanceOf` check

```
public boolean accept(Object obj)
```